# LED Matrix design in Multisim does not work in Tinkercad

Tags: led, potentiometer, led-matrix

[image: Right extreme of POT][image: Left extreme of POT]

[image: Tinkercad circuit][image: Left extreme in Tinkercad][image: Right extreme in Tinkercad]

We have this design in multisim and it works fine, the intended LEDs works fine in mutisim but when we used tinkercad to simulate, it does not work the same way. It is supposed to spell ECE (right extreme of pot) and 3-1 (left extreme of pot). Aside from the wrong connection in the potentiometer which should result in just showing 3-1 in right extreme and ECE in left extreme in tinkercad but somehow even switching the connections does not fix the problems with other LEDs. We also tried increasing resistances in some LEDs but it also does not work.

The second potentiometer connected in pink wiring in multisim should not affect the first potentiometer and we tested it, it works fine. the first bit has the only problem with some LEDs. what should we do? Do you have suggestions what to do? The tinkercad has almost the same outcome in actual application because we tried it before using tinkercad just to check if we did wrong in the wiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Multisim simulation is flawed.

Basically, your circuit has two "rails", one of which is powered at any given time based on the position of the potentiometer. Multisim is failing to account for the fact that there are multiple connections via the various fixed resistors between the two rails, so that when one is powered, the other is powered, too, with only a minor voltage drop. Tinkercad — and real life — are correctly showing this.

The fix is to add a diode in series with each of the fixed resistors to prevent this type of back-driving.

A simpler fix would be to have the LEDs that are lit by both rails connected directly to the power supply, but I'm guessing that you wanted them to fade in and out with the others for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Thank you sir for your suggestion! The LEDs almost works fine now, however there are still leakage currents to other LEDs that are not supposed to light up in both sides. They are dim instead of being off. Again we tried increasing the resistance but it does not really affect the LEDs that are not supposed to light up, aside from that we also tried decreasing the amount of current but they are still dim instead of being off.