# Ghosting in LED Matrix

Tags: led, potentiometer, led-matrix

[image: Left extreme of POT][image: Right extreme of POT]

[image: Schematic diagram][image: Ghost lit LED on right extreme of pot][image: Ghost lit LEDs on left extreme of the pot]

Some LEDs light up even if they are not supposed to. The LEDS should spell ECE on the right extreme of the pot, while 3-1 in the left extreme of the pot. So there are two scenarios, either show ECE or 3-1 depending on which side of the potentiometer was turned. The first two tinkercad diagrams show the supposed look of the lEDs in the both scenarios, however, there are ghost-lit LEDs as highlighted in the 4th and 5th photos. I think I saw similar problems in LED matrices here but they are all using ICs. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem? I have tried varying the resistance but it does not do anything. I also tried adding capacitors in series before rails but it made the circuit more complex than it has to.

I have encircled the LEDs that are not supposed to light up in the left and right scenarios on the 4th and 5th photos.

Comment: Give me a proper schematic, not a breadboard diagram

Comment: I have added the schematic diagram sir, I haven't added the diodes but they are all connected in series to the resistors on the left.

Comment: Please be more specific what is intended/expected behavior of your circuit and which particular LEDs are shining while "not supposed to".

Comment: "Some LEDs light up even if they are not supposed to."  What are you expecting to happen? Which LEDs are lighting up that shouldn't be? All the LEDs in a string receive the same current, so all the LEDs in a string will light up or none of them will. If the red arrows indicated LEDs that are lit then that seems to be exactly what is happening.

Comment: I edited the post again sir, sorry

Comment: I really don’t understand what exactly you’re trying to do, but maybe replace the Pots with switches?

Comment: I have added two pictures showing the ghost-lit LEDs, is it clear now?

Comment: Your LED are glowing very dimly because there is probably some small current running through them when you Pot is turned all the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LED Matrix design in Multisim does not work in Tinkercad](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/648567/led-matrix-design-in-multisim-does-not-work-in-tinkercad)

Comment: That post of mine is about the flaws of using multisim and how to fix this to arrive at my current circuit sir. This however, my problem revolves around turning off the LEDs that are not supposed to light up. So, no.

Answer (score 0):

R7 has the wiper connected to "plus supply":
You can adjust a very low resistance to one side, but the other one is still connected to plus via 10 kOhms unless the wiper loses contact.
(Using a (single pole) double throw switch instead of R7 would "fix" that. Using a 1 MOhm potentiometer would come close.)

R3, in contrast, is connected to both sides of the supply.

Comment: Sir, the R7 is connected to the positive supply

Comment: Yep. Different symbols used "locally, but battery would have been the same.

Comment: Sorry sir, I haven't mentioned it in the post, R7 is the only potentiometer used to manipulate the majority of the LEDs, R3 on the otherhand is used to control the remaining LEDs. It should not affect the rest of R7. And it R3 and its LEDs works fine. My problem is in the R7 bit.

Comment: Where should I add the switch and what kind of switch is it?